# RecyclerView has multiple Custom View instance as children. Custom View onClick animation is displayed in another one

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I have a RecyclerView populated with custom views, containing various information and an imageButton. 
This ImageButton should trigger a reveal animation when clicked, revealing a view over the previous one.

It does work when the RecyclerView contains only one item, but it starts to act weirdly as soon as the views start to be recycled.
In this case, when the imageButton is clicked in, say, item #4 the animation appears in item #2 (But it's random). It's a quite strange behavior, as both views (the first and the one to be revealed) are referenced inside the custom view, and not anywhere else.

All the logic to display the animation is inside the Custom view, triggered by the ViewModel injected in onBindViewHolder() (A new ViewModel is spawned in every onBindViewHolder).

I thought about using a RecyclerView.ItemAnimator, but i would need to call notifyItemChanged() from inside the view, which would be quite hacky.

Thanks for any suggestion.

**Update**

I'll add some code.

Here's my custom view.

```
public class CustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    @BindView(R.id.visible_view)
    View view1;
    @BindView(R.id.hidden_view)
    View view2;
    private ViewModel viewModel;


    public CustomView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_layout, this));
    }


    public void setViewModel(HomeworkCardVM viewModel) {
        view1.setViewModel(viewModel.subViewModel1());
        view2.setViewModel(viewModel.subViewModel2());

        viewModel.observeRevealShow()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
            if (aBoolean) {
                circularRevealView(visibleView, insertGradeView);
            }
        },Throwable::printStackTrace,() -> {});

        viewModel.observeRevealHide()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
            circularHideView(insertGradeView, visibleView);
        },Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> {});
    }

    private void circularHideView(View visibleView, View invsisibleView) {

        // get the center for the clipping circle
        int cx = visibleView.getWidth() / 2;
        int cy = visibleView.getHeight() / 2;

        // get the initial radius for the clipping circle
        float initialRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);

        // create the animation (the final radius is zero)
        Animator anim =
                ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(visibleView, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);

        // make the view invisible when the animation is done
        anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                visibleView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                invsisibleView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        // start the animation
        anim.start();

    }

    private void circularRevealView(View visibleView, View invisibleView) {

        // get the center for the clipping circle
        int cx = visibleView.getWidth() /2;
        int cy = visibleView.getHeight() /2;

        // get the final radius for the clipping circle
        float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);

        // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
        Animator anim =
                ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(invisibleView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

        visibleView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
        invisibleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // make the view visible and start the animation
        anim.start();
    }

}
```

And here's the very basic adapter.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public Adapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public HomeworkViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.view_holder, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.bindItem(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

And the even more basic view holder.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.custom_view)
    CustomView customView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bindItem(Item item){
        ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(item);
        customView.setViewModel(viewModel);
    }
}
```

My gut are telling me that somehow the view referenced in                     `circularRevealView(visibleView, insertGradeView);` gets assigned to another RecyclerView item when recycled, I will investigate

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's always easier for people to help you if they have some [piece of code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work on - please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Thank you, I've provided some minimal code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you do this. The only good way to do this is:

- create a custom itemanimator
- implement item change functions
- call notifiyitemchanged when you want to animate a particular view

As you suggested doing animations like yours is a good way to fail because of how recycleview works. You should do all animations with itemanimator to keep everything in synch.

Comment: I'll try moving the custom view code in the view holder and adding a custom item animator. I'll update you asap. Thanks.

Comment: Okay great, I'm working on it and seems like I'm on the right track. Although, I'm having some more problem with the ItemAnimator and the RecyclerView behavior. Could you please take a read at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39223850/6770732) question? Thanks.