# OnCreateViewHolder is still called even if ItemAnimator.canReuseUpdatedViewHolder() returns true

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I'm building a change animation for my RecyclerView. I've overriden `canReuseUpdatedViewHolder()` to return `true` in order to retain the previous viewholder. I start the animation in `animateChange()` and call `dispatchAnimationFinished()` as soon as it ends. Params `oldHolder` and `newHolder` are the same instance in `animateChange()`.

Then, as soon as the animation starts, RecyclerView's `onBindViewHolder()` is called for every child in the list. Surprisingly, only for the animated item a new ViewHolder is spawned in `onCreateViewHolder()` which as I've understood is not the correct behavior. For every other child the old ViewHolder is bound in `onBindViewHolder()`.

As a side note, `onBindViewHolder()` is called too soon, before the animation is finished. Even if                   `dispatchAnimationFinished(holder)` is called after the animation is finished.

Here's the ItemAnimator subclass.

```
public class CustomItemAnimator extends DefaultItemAnimator {


    @Override
    public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canReuseUpdatedViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull List<Object> payloads) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean animateChange(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder oldHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder newHolder, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo preLayoutInfo, @NonNull ItemHolderInfo postLayoutInfo) {
        CustomHolder holder = (CustomHolder) newHolder;
        CustomView customView = holder.customView;
        Animator animator = customView.revealAnimation();
        animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                dispatchAnimationFinished(holder);
            }
        });
        animator.start();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and here's the custom view animation code:

`CustomView.java`

```
public Animator revealAnimation() {
    return circularRevealView(visibleView, hiddenView);
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private Animator circularRevealView(View visibleView, View invisibleView) {

    // get the center for the clipping circle
    int cx = visibleView.getWidth() / 2;
    int cy = visibleView.getHeight() / 2;

    // get the final radius for the clipping circle
    float finalRadius = (float) Math.hypot(cx, cy);

    // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
    Animator anim =
            ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(invisibleView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

    visibleView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
    invisibleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    // return the animation for later use
    return anim;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

animateChange(...) is called after notifyDataSetChanged(),it means that onBindViewHolder() goes before animateChange(...).and the state of holder has already changed.maybe you can do it this

```
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                visibleView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
                invisibleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                dispatchAnimationFinished(holder);
            }
        });
```